# Installing a steam game on a secondary drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, games, steam

I'm trying to install a steam game on a secondary drive. I have a partition set up and mounted at `/media/impulse/{uuid}`. However, when I open Settings > Downloads > Steam Library Folders > +, the directory picker doesn't list `/mnt` or `/media`. Why?

[image: screenshot]

In the Gnome Files View it is shown

[image: Shown in Files]

Comment: Why not mount your drive at /home/username/steam? Then it should be simple. Strange that you cannot use /media but then lots of different things can be mounted there so perhaps steam have not allowed it

Comment: That also didn't work. It just misses half of the directories.

Comment: Based on the answer OP is using the Pop_OS. I am voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that problem with install steam by Terminal and not the PopOS Shop flatpack.

Step 1:

```
sudo apt-get install steam -y
```

When the installer is done, you start steam by terminal

Step 2:

```
steam
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer in the description of the app in Pop!_Shop:

> Note: To add a game library on another drive, first you need to grant
> the app access to it:
>
> flatpak override --user --filesystem=/path/to/your/Steam/Library
> com.valvesoftware.Steam

Comment: Just so it will be clear for others. You are using a flatpak version of the steam app? Is that correct? If so this will not be helpful for a regular package

Comment: Indeed ^^^The regular .deb has no such limitation, snaps and flatpacks do. And if you're using Pop!_OS then your question is off-topic.